# Using react native firebase with library react-native-google-mobile-ads in test version

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob

I moved recently from using React Native Firebase Admob library to display ads to the react-native-google-mobile-ads lib.
I followed the installation guide but I am missing something and wanted to check if someone could help.
I

- added the library react-native-google-mobile-ads in my react native project
- executed the pod install command
- created two app (ios & android) in my admob console
- inserted both id in app.json

```
{
  "name": "MyWod",
  "displayName": "My Wod",
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-XXX",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-XXX"
  }
}
```

And I am trying to just initialisze the library

```
const initAds = async () => {
    try {
      let result = await mobileAds().initialize();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initAds();
    store.dispatch(getResults());
    store.dispatch(getMovmentsAction());
  }, []);
```

I only receive a timeout as response
`[{"description": "Timeout.", "name": "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds", "state": 0}]`

I am missing smething bvious ?

I tried to initilize the library and only get a timeout response.